# Converting a recipe from 6qt Instant Pot to 8qt

Tags: pressure-cooker, conversion, instant-pot

I have an 8qt Instant Pot. Most of the recipes online are for 6qt Instant Pots. I find that since my 8qt takes a lot longer to come to pressure (about 18 minutes, depending on the amount of liquid inside the pot) than the 6qt ones do, my food often ends up getting overcooked if I follow the instructions exactly.

Is this normal? How should I convert recipes from 6qt to 8qt?

Comment: I don't know if that's normal, but I would think that the main factor for pressure would be airspace, amount of water (or something else to evaporate), and heat.  If no one else has a better suggestion, you might want to try the 'pot-in-pot' method, so that the thing to be cooked isn't sitting at the bottom of the pan, then add water below it.  (although, you may need to drain the pot & reduce the sauce afterwards)

Comment: So, is this question about adjusting a recipe for ingredients or cook time?

Comment: @dougp01 Cook time

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you may have to experiment.

I believe the problem lies in the fact that more water takes longer to reach temperature, given the same burner arrangement.  This means whatever you have inside the pot is exposed to the lower grade heat for a longer period and by the time you reach full pressure, the food may already be over cooked.  I have not tried this myself but consider using preheated water at the beginning in order to shorten the overall cook time.